# Is it possible to put a new SSD into my work laptop and then put the old SSD back in when I need to return it to work?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, m.2

My personal laptop is, in a word is f**ked.

I was planning on using my work laptop until I can get a new one, it's an HP Elitebook 830 G5. However the work laptop has limited functionality due to admin rights being restricted so I can't install anything I would use normally.

If I put my SSD M.2 into the laptop and install Windows 10 will I have any issues when I put the work M.2 with Windows Enterprise back in?

Comment: Does your company policy / IT department allow this? Seems like a violation of most corporate policies on using their equipment

Comment: The policy states company laptops can be used for some personal use but not specifically swapping SSDs in order to get full functionality!

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to get my own windows 10 log in on the laptop? But I can't see a way to do this as it goes directly to the works domain.

Comment: In general when doing something out of the ordinary to a work laptop it is best to ask. Would be a shame to get in trouble for something preventable.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is usually just fine, as long as you don't change any Bios settings, while the company M.2 card isn't in the device.
(Changing Bios settings may invalidate the Windows install on the company M.2 and then you will have some explaining to do to the IT guys in the office.)

In some rare cases the company may have configured the laptop in such a way that it will not accept a non-company Windows install. In that case it just won't work (but there is no harm done in trying).

Be careful to fully shutdown (NOT hibernate or sleep) the laptop before changing the M.2 card. You may corrupt the Windows installation of your swap cards with a "sleeping" Windows installation on it.

Please note: your company may have policies that disallow this practice and as they own the laptop it is their rules. You better check first if this won't get you in trouble with your employer.

Comment: Thank you for the information, the system BIOS is password protected so this will rule out any changes being implimented.

Comment: It's probably wise for me to be patient until I can get my own. thanks again